# Прописная или строчная буква в слове «закон»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как правильно?

1. Мы прошли **з**акон всемирного тяготения.
2. Мы прошли **З**акон всемирного тяготения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**Предложения со словосочетанием «закон всемирного тяготения»**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD+%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (КАРТАСЛОВ.РУ):

*Ньютон открыл **з**акон всемирного тяготения, доказал существование статического электричества* (Г. П. Шалаева, Кто есть кто в мире открытий и изобретений, 2009).

*Частицы газов также подчиняются **з**акону всемирного тяготения* (Николай Дорожкин, Краткая история Вселенной, 2019).

*Кроме того, он сформулировал **з**акон всемирного тяготения* (Стивен Хокинг, Теория всего. От сингулярности до бесконечности: происхождение и судьба Вселенной, 2006).